# Using tx2 dev-kit CSI camera on the Jetson xavier in Python3

Tags: python, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

The only way that I am able to accomplish opening a live camera stream on the Xavier is launching gstreamer from console

```
gst-launch-1.0 nvarguscamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=1024, height=768, framerate=120/1, format=NV12' ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink -e
```

When i try any video capture command in python or c++ i am constantly getting errors about "camera failed to open" or "video stream type error" 
Ive tried this in opencv 4, 3.4, 3.3 to no avail.

I do not think its that way my opencv build is configured but possibly a way that the xavier camera capture must be instanced. Any type of sample python implementation of live video capture using the tx2 dev-kit camera would be highly helpful?

Thanks

Comment: add the complete error log. Use the tool `GST_DEBUG` , to get more information about what is not working in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the Jetson camera through the gstreamer api.

C++ example

```
cv::VideoCapture capture("nvarguscamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=1024, height=768, framerate=120/1, format=NV12' ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! appsink");
```

or Python

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('nvarguscamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=1024, height=768, framerate=120/1, format=NV12' ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! appsink')
```

However, you might be missing gstreamer from your OpenCv build. If this is not working you might need to rebuild your OpenCv with all gstreamer features enabled/dependencies solved.